# Ouya - dimensions too large

Tags: android, ouya

I'm testing my video player on an OUYA device and it crashes almost immediately with the "dimension too large" error (see logcat dump below). If anyone knows of a work-around or a way to set a maximum dimension, I'll be grateful.

```
D/MySurface(2651): surfaceCreated
W/InputDispatcher(319): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '41daf688 tv.ouya.console.wallpaper.OozeService (server)'
I/WindowState(319): WIN DEATH: Window{41daf688 tv.ouya.console.wallpaper.OozeService paused=false}
I/WindowManager(319): WINDOW DIED Window{41daf688 tv.ouya.console.wallpaper.OozeService paused=false}
E/SurfaceFlinger(109): dimensions too large 2560 x 1472
E/SurfaceFlinger(109): createNormalSurfaceLocked() failed (Invalid argument)
W/WindowStateAnimator(319): OutOfResourcesException creating surface
I/WindowManager(319): Out of memory for surface!  Looking for leaks...
W/WindowManager(319): No leaked surfaces; killing applicatons!
W/ActivityManager(319): Killing processes Free memory at adjustment 0
W/ActivityManager(319): Killing ProcessRecord{41d9cae8 2651:example.android.player/u0a37} (adj 0): Free memory
W/WindowManager(319): Looks like we have reclaimed some memory, clearing surface for retry.
W/WindowManager(319): Due to memory failure, waiting a bit for next layout
```

I've tried changing the resolutions via this post as well without any success: http://forums.ouya.tv/discussion/2170/setting-resolution-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around for this using a Surface callback with a pre-set max for width and height:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Rect rect = holder.getSurfaceFrame();
    if (rect.width() > maxWidth || rect.height() > maxHeight) {
        holder.setFixedSize(maxWidth, maxHeight);
    }
}
```